# Mysql xor operator does not properly work, when one of condition is null

Tags: mysql, database, xor

I need to add a clause for select where either a record equals the value or equals null.

```
select * 
from table 
where column = 123 or column is null;
```

As a result I get

```
|column|
  123
  123
  null
  null
```

When I try to use xor

```
select * 
from table 
where column = 123 xor column is null;
```

I get either only 123 records

```
|column|
  123
  123
```

or, if there is no 123, I got nothing

|column|

But I need, when there is no 123 records to get only null ones. So basically my desired result will be:

```
|db column|      |column with 123 clause|    |column with 125 clause|
  123                     123                        null
  123                     123                        null
  null
  null
  124
```

Could you please help me with this issue?

Comment: XOR will not return your values as your column can't be at the same time 123 and NULL, there fore your query makes no sense at all

Comment: XOR was never expect to handle null, was it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want the third and fourth row returned if the first and second are not returned, right? This cannot be expressed with a simple `where` clause. Try

```sql
select * from table where column=123
  or column is null and not exists
     (select * from table where column=123)
```

Regarding your `xor` observation: I assume that

```sql
column=123 xor column is null
```

is equivalent to

```sql
column=123 and column is not null or
column<>123 and column is null
```

But when `column = null`, the expression `column<>123` is false, therefore the overall condition is also false.

Comment: oh, it's like for xor 0 xor 0 = 0, now I got it, I've missed that part, thank you for your help and the explanation